# list.setGrouped(true) DOESN'T work?? How can I do it?

Tags: javascript, extjs, touch

I'm trying to set the 'grouped' property to TRUE for a list at run time by follwoing sencha touch API there is a 'setGrouped()' method but it's not existing!!! if you click 'source' at top right side in sencha touch docs it take you to list.js but I serached for setGrouped and NOTHING.

I'm using sencha touch 2.4.1

Please help, How can I set grouped to true at run time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a grouper on the list's store: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-grouper

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch adds setter- and getter-functions for properties dynamically - that's why you don't find a *Ext.dataview.List.getGrouped()* or *Ext.dataview.List.setGrouped()* function in the api source code.

To set the *grouped* property of a list dynamically via *Ext.dataview.List.getGrouped()*, you have to:

1. configure the list's store with a *Ext.util.Grouper* instance with a *sortProperty* and *groupFn*
2. set the list's *grouped* property config to *true* as default - if I don't do this, e.g. leave *grouped: false* or don't add the config at all, I get an error at runtime (something with *Cannot read property '0' of undefined*)
3. at runtime, get a reference to the list and call *setGrouped(true | false);*

For me, this solution works and I can group/ungroup lists in Sencha Touch 2.4.1 at runtime following these steps.

Hope it helps - Cherrio!